# Multiprocessing: main process is not terminated

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, child-process, zombie-process

I have this code:

```
import vlc
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process

def lul():
    song = vlc.MediaPlayer("Himeringo - Shinitai-chan.mp3")
    song.audio_set_volume(50)
    song.play()

    sleep(5)
    while song.is_playing():
        print('&')
        sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    k = Process(target=lul)
    k.daemon = False
    k.start()
```

And when I execute it, main process keeps running:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNZFu.png)

I'm sure that highlighted guy is `main`, because when I added a *while True* loop that was printing things at the end and then killed this guy, it stopped printing this things (but proceeded with printing &s) and continued playing the song

My goal is to keep process with song alive, while there is nothing else running. And the main continuing as zombie isn't what I want.

I [can kill it manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsdW7.png), and the song will keep playing, but that is not the way.

So, the question is: why main process stays alive when it reaches end line? Once I divided by zero, but it continued as zombie despite that fact: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYoJx.png)

Comment: With 428 questions on [multiprocessing terminate process](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=multiprocessing+terminate+process) this is surely a duplicate. Please close

Comment: You simply want to non-blocking fork a child process? or call lul() from __main__()? or what? Better to tell us what you actually want to do, not just complain that the code isn't doing it.

Comment: @smci Chill man, I wasn't able to find a similar question (mostly because of my small english vocabulary, but I'm working on it), plus Mr. Zwinck - professional psychic - already gave me really good answer. How do I close the question? If it is done by choosing the best answer, then I've done it.

Comment: asdfadf it's ok, it was closed already as duplicate. (That's a different thing to accepting an answer). Anyway I posted because there were already hundreds of questions on this and similar topics. Their titles and findability aren't great though, this is something that can be improved in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `multiprocessing` always waits for the child to complete.  But `subprocess.Popen()` does not.  However, `subprocess.Popen()` launches any new program, not necessarily a Python one, and does not directly call a Python function.  You could do something like `Popen(['python', __file__, '--child'])` and implement your script so that when `sys.argv` contains `--child` (hint: use `argparse`), it will just call `lul()`.

However, there is no need to do any of this--your end goal here seems to be that `lul()` runs in a Python interpreter, and no extra Python interpreter remains.  So don't start a second interpreter in the first place--simply call `lul()` and be done with it.

Comment: I'd recommend `sys.executable` as the command to execute.